# jQuery to Make Ajax Request with Django

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-forms

I am trying to interact with the server using jQuery and Django, but I am receiving this in my Chrome console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/rate/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) jquery.min.js:6
x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send jquery.min.js:6
x.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:6
x.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous function) jquery.js:14
x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
y.handle
```

And this from my terminal:

```
rating = request.POST.get['rating']
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable
```

**Template:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <form action="#" id="rate-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="like">Like<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="dislike">Dislike
        <input type="submit" value="Rate">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rate-form').submit(function(e){
        $.post( '/rate/', $(this).serialize(), function() {
            alert('Submitted'); 
        }); 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Views:**

```
def test(request):
    rating = request.POST.get['rating']
    html = "Your rating is %s" % rating
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

And my "/rate/" url is pointed to the test view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Ajax or jQuery, it is a Python error. `get` is a method: you either do `request.POST['rating']` or `request.POST.get('rating')`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not getting my data from the form in my view with that change, but I'm also not getting any errors now. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. What do you see as the value of `rating` in the view?

Comment: So I did some testing and the page I have the form on is being loaded into part of the page a user is viewing without updating the whole page. When I put the form on the main template then it works fine, but then I don't have access to things like the post's id being hidden in the form. Thoughts?